# MySQL version fails to execute geometry query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

If I run this query

```
SELECT region_id FROM shape_region WHERE ST_Within(point(-117.10480, 32.72204),shape_region.shape)=1
```

on <strike>MySQL</strike> MariaDB version 10.1.13-MariaDB, there are no problems.

But on MySQL version 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 I get this error

> Binary geometry function st_within given two geometries of different srids: 0 and 1, which should have been identical.

I do not understand the error, is there a comparable query I can use on this version of MySQL?

Comment: Mariadb is not mysql, you ate comparing apples with pears.

Comment: Edited, I think the question still stands on what a comparable query might be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer found at this link

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79282

Compatible query that works on both MySQL and MariaDB:

```
SELECT region_id FROM shape_region WHERE ST_Contains( SHAPE, ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(-122.392128 37.795653)', 1 ) )
```

As explained in the link

> You can't compare a shape in one spatial reference system (SRID 1) with a point in another spatial reference system (SRID 0). The POINT() function[1] will always return a point in SRID 0, which is the unitless, Cartesian default spatial reference system.
>
> In order to do the intended comparison, the point has to be in the same spatial reference system as the shape. E.g., use the SRID parameter of ST_GeomFromText()[2]:

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the same problem with MySQL [5.7.18] and your solution worked perfectly!